# Cron job failed in Google App Engine Flexible environment

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cron, app-engine-flexible

I m migrating my PHP application from [Google App engine Standard Environment to Flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/migrating).

My application working fine with database and send grid. But Cron jobs are failed.

I could not find what I missed to run a Cron job in GAE Flexible environment.I gave sample application code [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XxyZBWussxx5zaGZLKbfTpevmNUw_alIGn0XfYK5iCQ/edit#gid=0).

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
document_root: web

handlers:

- url: /crontest
script: crontest.php

- url: .*
script: index.php

#[START env]
env_variables:
MYSQL_DBNAME: CRONDB
MYSQL_USER: root
MYSQL_PASSWORD: root123
MYSQL_CONNECTION: /cloudsql/project-id:us-central1:testphp7
#[END env]

#[START cloudsql_settings]
# Use the connection name obtained when configuring your Cloud SQL instance.
beta_settings:
cloud_sql_instances: "project-id:us-central1:testphp7"
#[END cloudsql_settings]
```

**cron.yaml**

```
- description: cron test
url: /crontest
schedule: every day 17:00
timezone: Asia/Kolkata
```

**web/connection.php**

```
<?php    
    $con = new mysqli(null,$_SERVER['MYSQL_USER'],$_SERVER['MYSQL_PASSWORD'],$_SERVER['MYSQL_DBNAME'],null,$_SERVER['MYSQL_CONNECTION']);
?>
```

**web/crontest.php**

```
<?php

include "connection.php";

$ATERM_spcallstmt="INSERT INTO SAMPLE(TEST_NO)VALUES('9876')";
$con->query($ATERM_spcallstmt);
?>
```

**web/index.php**

```
<?php
echo " Test Cron in FE";
?>
```

**Create table Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE(TEST_NO VARCHAR(250));
```

**Log from API Console**

```
18:57:00.000172.18.0.3 - - [02/May/2017:13:27:00 +0000] "GET /crontest.php HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)"
{
textPayload: "172.18.0.3 - - [02/May/2017:13:27:00 +0000] "GET /crontest.php HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "
insertId: "epwcgng8mcw86z"
resource: {…}
timestamp: "2017-05-02T13:27:00Z"
labels: {…}
logName: "projects/project-id/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fstdout"
}
```

I got HTTP 404 & Cron Failed.

Please help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not see this particular setting
"cloud_sql_instances" in your app.yaml from this guide (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql)
see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks ankitk, I fixed the issue, I added $_SERVER['HTTP_X_APPENGINE_CRON'] =true;  in  crontest.php. Now working

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the cron is trying to accessing `/web/crontest.php` which is incorrect path in your case. I suspect you still have old cron config alive?

Comment: Thanks Takashi, I fixed the issue, I added $_SERVER['HTTP_X_APPENGINE_CRON'] =true;  in  crontest.php. Now working. I re-edited my post